# Comparison between two ODE solutions with different coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this ODE of the Lotka–Volterra form:

$$dX_t=X_t(a-b(t)X_t)dt,X_0=x_0>0$$

in which the parameter $b$ is time dependent.
I would like build and explicit bound for the solution of the latter, then I thought of grabbing a lower bound for $b(t)$ namely $c<|b(t)|$ for all $t$ , and then to obtain a new ODE replacing $b(t)$ by $c$.

$$dY_t=Y_t(a-cY_t)dt,Y_0=x_0>0.$$

In [this article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82254543.pdf) some comparison theorems are presented, but they are not applicable to this case. I am pretty sure that in my case we have that $Y_t\geq X_t$ for all $t$, but I am not able to prove it formally.

Could you please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use the comparison theorems you attached but here is an approach. I will ignore the finite escape time issues that can arise in this DE since I think they aren't difficult to address.

If you make the substition $X_t = V(X_t, t) e^{at}$ and $Y_t = W(Y_t, t) e^{at}$ you'll arrive at the ODEs
$$\begin{aligned}
 dV &= - b(t)~V(X_t, t)^2~e^{a t}~dt\\
 dW &= - c~W(X_t, t)^2~e^{a t}~dt.
\end{aligned}$$
Note that by our choice of substition, the initial conditions imposed on $V$ and $W$ remain equal.
Rewriting the now separable ODEs gives
$$\begin{aligned}
 \frac{1}{V(X_t, t)^2} dV &= - b(t) e^{a t}\\
 \frac{1}{W(X_t, t)^2} dW &= - c e^{a t}.
\end{aligned}$$
Define a new error state $E = \frac{1}{W} - \frac{1}{V}$ and find that it observes the dynamics
$$
dE = -\frac{1}{W^2} dW + \frac{1}{V^2} dV = (c-b(t))e^{at}~dt
$$
with initial condition $E(0)=0.$ I think at this point you can say something based on the relationship between $b(t)$ and $c.$ In particular, with $b(t)>c>0$ you'll have $\int_0^{E(t)} dE \leq 0$ Equipped with that you can conclude $\frac{1}{W}\leq \frac{1}{V}$ and then $W \geq V.$

Comment: Nice! How did you come up with this solution? Do you have some reference?

Comment: @RScrlli not sure if someone has done this explicitly in literature, probably have. How i came up with it basically boils down to the structure of the problem. The comparison you are making is only in the $X^2$ terms so it would make your life easier if you first eliminated the linear driving term with variation of parameters. After that, defining an error state is a pretty common thing to do in control theory to figure out the relative growth/decay/stability/etc. of a signal so coming up with a good error state that cancels out the nasty bits ($W^2$ and $V^2$) is all that is left to do.